# Insert Base64 Images to Array PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I'm trying to insert Blob images retrieved from MySQL into an array using a while loop.

The database statement selected all images then i need to pass them all into an array.

So in theory, i should have an array of base64 encoded image corresponding to each record from my database.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
$sql = "SELECT img from artistlocation";

    try{
        $db = new db();
        $db = $db->connect(); 
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $data = array();
        while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))

        {
            //$result = base64_encode(); ---- Something here im guessing
            $data[] = $result;
        }
       print_r ($data);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
```

Comment: You might want to update your question to include any errors or incorrect output you're seeing in addition to what sort of output you'd like to see or expected results. As it is, it's kind of hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: Did you try `base64_encode()`? What happened?

Comment: @AbraCadaver i did try that yes. It threw an error saying base64_encode() required a parameter

Comment: Basic programmin: `$data[] = base64_encode($result['img']);`

Comment: Or since you use `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` you'll want `$result->img`

Comment: @AbraCadaver It works thank you however my knowlege on PDO is limited. I simply want to put the base64 image into a basic chronolgical array. What PDO Fetch is the best to use for this?

Comment: Either one, just the nomenclature is different. `->img` for object `['img']` for array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this question came from AbraCadaver.

```
 $sql = "SELECT img from artistlocation";

    try{
        $db = new db();
        $db = $db->connect(); 
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $data = array();
        while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))    
        {
            $data[] = base64_encode($result->img);
        }
```

Thanks guys for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I see big issue i your code..

You use the same variable, `$result`, for fetching mysql row result and image content.

Second, you miss to encoding to base64 the file content.

Here is my solution:

```
$sql = "SELECT img from artistlocation";

try{
    $db = new db();
    $db = $db->connect(); 
    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
    $data = array();
    while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))

    {
        $data[] = base64_encode($result['img']);
    }
   print_r ($data);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
}
```

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: Where did this come from??? `$im = file_get_contents('/path/to/file/filename.gif');`

Comment: Should be `$result["img"]`

Comment: i agree with @AbraCadaver I need the image to come from my database not locally

Comment: What you save in `img`? image url? or image content ?

Comment: I've uploaded a Blob PNG file @4EACH

Comment: @4EACH Yes it works now. See mine and Abras comments above :)